# Weird parameter in youtube iframe player video url

Tags: events, google-analytics, url-parameters, youtube-iframe-api

I use youtube's iframe player api to embed videos and track plays in my site. When a user click play I send an event to google analytics with a label that is either a data attribute of the player or if none is present then the url of the video being played. I get the url by calling the following method:

```
player.getVideoUrl()
```

Where player is the iframe generated by youtube's API.

This has been working great so far, except today I got a strange url label in analytics. I recognize the ID of the video as one that is played pretty regularly, but there was also a weird parameter attached to it, **ebc**:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IDOFVIDEO&**ebc**=RANDOMSTRINGOFCHARACTERS

What is that **ebc** parameter? Why would it have been generated by the getVideoUrl() method, which up to this point has only returned the url of the embed? Anyone else seen this before? Worth noting that with that parameter the URL breaks.

Comment: I've had the exact same thing happen, and it's also affecting my Analytics events. Did you ever get to the bottom of it? I'd be interested to know what's causing the `ebc` parameter and what it means.

Comment: I have not figured it out yet. It hasn't happened in a while. I should maybe report it as a bug to google, see if the official forums are any help.